# TCP session with Spring Integration framework

Tags: tcp, spring-integration

I'm trying to create an iso8385 TCP server using Spring Integration. A typical scenario would be the following:

- a client connects to the server and deposits an ISO8385 message
- the server processes the message
- the server formulates a response and closes the connection

I want to keep track of each new TCP connection, and create an identifier for it, in order to associate each processing to the connected client. But I don't know how to do that. The idea would be to have:

- a tcp inbound adapter, that transforms ISO8385 into a java class
- a service activator which will process the message
- a tcp outbound adapter, that transforms a java class into an ISO8385 message
- a channel (but where ?)
- a identifier for a TCP session that is shared between all of these

Does anyone know how to perform this ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually `<int-tcp:tcp-inbound-gateway>` does the stuff for you:

- you configure `<int-tcp:tcp-connection-factory type="server">`
- inject it into the `<int-tcp:tcp-inbound-gateway>`
- all other `correlation` logic is encapsulated in the last one

I have some experience with `iso8385`, but I don't think that there is a reason to get deal here with `MCC` or `terminalId` to correlate messages.

Would be more interest to provide some routing logic for `ISO message types`. But it is a different story...

Comment: Would it be possible to have a sample piece of code ?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/tcp-client-server/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/tcpServerConnectionDeserialize-context.xml